# Is dynamic content reloaded on a resize event triggered?

Tags: jquery, window-resize

I want to load a different picture depending on the window width. So I've built an empty divide in the body of the document and I'm going to set its content (the image source) by means of a jquery script.

Now I want that changing the orientation of the device a new query is triggered, so I've put the code in a `resize` method.

What happens if a `resize` event is triggered and the picture that has to be loaded is the same as the previous one (suppose that the screen size changes from 799px to 800px)? Is it loaded anyway wasting bandwidth or it isn't loaded again?

Comment: You can check this using the developer tools on your browser, and seeing if a network request is made.

Comment: I think if you are using AJAX...everytime it will load and it will take the loading time evertime.

Comment: Rajiv007: I don't think that he's using AJAX. Nevertheless, the comment that you made about AJAX is not entirely correct. It really depends whether a cache buster is used or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, no. However, the behavior really depends on the caching definition that is set by the server and the compatibility of the client used (there shouldn't be any issues with standard browsers).

As suggested above, you can use the developer tools (Network tab) [image]to check whether the resource has been reloaded. You will generally need to check whether you got a standard 200 response, a 200 (from cache) response or a 304 (Not modified). The major difference between the 200 (from cache) and 304 response, is that with 304 a request will be issued to the server and the server will respond with a 304, which means that the cached item is valid (a request will be issued but the content will not be re-downloaded), while with the 200 (from cache), no request will be issued to the server. You can learn more about the two [here](http://www.benhallbenhall.com/2012/03/http-codes-200-from-cache-304/).

Another alternative would be to use something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), if for some reason you can't access the dev tools.

Comment: Sometimes I'm getting a 304 response and sometimes a 200 response. In any case it doesn't seem to reload the picture as I gradually resize the window. Sometimes I'm getting "pending" in the latency column. Is this troubling?

Comment: If you have control over the server and the ability to change the cache response header, assuming that images will not change (at least not frequently) then you should change the header types so that the browser will not even issue the requests. With regards to the "pending" status, does it change after the image loaded? I guess that it's a result of the fact that the browser does issue a request to the server to get the 304.